# Linking libraries in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following make file

```
EXECUTABLE       := sub
CCFILES          := SubFilHost.cpp 
include ../../common/common_opencl.mk
```

I want to include 3 libraries in this make file name libpng.a,libpng16.a and libz.a.
How should I write them in this make file for them to get included. the libraries are in the same place as of the source files as of now.

the file is here[common_opencl.mk](https://github.com/sschaetz/nvidia-opencl-examples/blob/master/OpenCL/common/common_opencl.mk)

Comment: Given makefile doesn't define any targets. If it builds anything, it is defined in `common_opencl.mk` - you probably should add its contents to question. By if it uses conventional make variable names - it is very likely you should add something like `LIBS:=libpng.a libz.a` _before_ including `common_opencl.mk`

Comment: ya the file defines the targets which is here https://github.com/sschaetz/nvidia-opencl-examples/blob/master/OpenCL/common/common_opencl.mk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no direct way to influence behavior `common_opencl.mk` defines. However, you can redefine linking target with your own, e.g.:

```
EXECUTABLE       := sub
CCFILES          := SubFilHost.cpp 
include ../../common/common_opencl.mk

EXTRALIBS:=libpng.a libz.a

$(TARGET): makedirectories $(OBJS) Makefile
    $(VERBOSE)$(LINKLINE) $(EXTRALIBS)
```

(this is full Makefile example)